# How to let TypeScript know about a function attached the the global namespace

Tags: typescript, global, typescript-typings

I've got a good grasp of TypeScript and use it often so I know how to do most things.

Assume I have a function attached the `global`, for example `getThisOrThat()` is the event. This function is attached to global but it's also part of a module that's in the project's node_modules. It has perfect typings to work with but since the module doesn't export functions directly (remember they're attached to global).

So now I can't do `import { getThisOrThat } from 'the-module';` because the transpiled would be:

`module.getThisOrThat() /// crash and burn cause it's on global :)`

I can't `require()` the module either because, it's the same of course when transpiled.

To pass the compiler I currently know of two options.

- `declare var getThisOrThat: Function;`
- `global.getThisOrThat()`

Both of those work to pass the compiler check but I really want to give the entire project the benefit of the typings for this module with global functions. I've also tried adding it with a `<ref />` but no luck there.

Comment: Have you tried creating a d.ts file that contains your globals?

Comment: I've not because I'm not sure what that would look like. I've got a d.ts for the global functions but I can't import it bc transpiled it's calling the module.function. so what would the d.ts look like and how to require/import it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have typings that declare some function in a module, but at runtime you want to use it as if it was global? Then you can add your own d.ts file that [augments global namespace](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#augmenting-globalmodule-scope-from-modules):

```
declare module 'the-module-global' {

import * as TheModule from 'the-module';// this import is used for typechecking only

global {
    var getThisOrThat : typeof TheModule.getThisOrThat;
}

}
```

Comment: Your wording is exactly what I need. Let me give that a try. Thanks!